# Offset curve bevel extrusion

Tags: objects, extrude, path, bevel

Learning Blender. Can anyone tell me is there a way how to offset this piece.

What I have here is path which is set on bevel extrusion with start and end values changed with circle curve as a sweep object. Now I would like to know how to offset this piece along the path. Analog to this would be probably After Effects Trim Path.

[image]

Comment: How about changing the start and end values simulateously?

Answer (score 1):

When you hover over the *Bevel Start* and *End* Properties you can press <kbd>I</kbd> to create a keyframe on them. The keyframes can be offset (move <kbd>G</kbd>) and duplicated in the *graph editor*.

[image: offseting bevel keyframes]

You could continuously Duplicate and Move the keyframes for both of the start and end values, or animate them independently.

[image: animating them independently]